# Get name of original rake task or pass argument

Tags: ruby, rake

I have a script which I want to call via a rake task like this:

```
task init_general: %i[call_step validate_step init]
task init_sub: %i[call_step validate_step init]
```

If you can see, it is somehow the same. But in the init script, there is a small code piece which should only be executed if init_general is called. Is it possible to pass arguments here like?

```
task init_general: %i[call_step validate_step init("true")]
task init_sub: %i[call_step validate_step init("false")]
```

or define some kind of global parameter which is then valid for all scripts?

```
task init_general: %i[call_step validate_step init] do
  my_setting1 = "true"
end
task init_sub: %i[call_step validate_step init] do
  my_setting1 = "false"
end
```

Or to get the orignial task name in the script? Nothing was working so far, so I wanted to ask if i am on the correct way. Thank you.

Comment: Or you could split `init` task in two.

Comment: Maybe `init` should rather be a method that is called from within your tasks.

Comment: At the end, i did both. Using Methods and splitted it. Thanks